# Start scroll indicator at specific point on page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the below HTML, CSS and JavaScript to make this scroll indicator work. The only issue I have is that I want the scroll progress to start when the user is about 10% the way down the page.

Any idea how to get that work?

`<div class="line" id="scrollIndicator"></div>`

```
<script>
   const scrollIndicatorElt = document.getElementById('scrollIndicator');
const maxScrollableHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
window.addEventListener('scroll', moveScrollIndicator);
    function moveScrollIndicator() {
  const percentage = ((window.scrollY) / maxScrollableHeight) * 100;
  scrollIndicatorElt.style.width = percentage + '%';
}
  </script>
```

```
.line {
      background: #00ba74 ;
      height: 7px;
      border-radius: 0px;
      width: 0%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you not just set it to `(percentage + 10) + '%'`?

Comment: That leaves a piece of the indicator visible if the user scrolls back up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be accomplished by using an if statement.

```
if (percentage >=10){
    scrollIndicatorElt.style.width = percentage + '%';
} else {
    scrollIndicatorElt.style.width = 0 + '%';
}
```

This only expands the indicator if the percentage scroll is 10 percent more than the page's height. It might be hard to see at first but if you adjust your window so that there is only a small amount of room to scroll you should be able to see it not render until it gets passed 10.

```js
const scrollIndicatorElt = document.getElementById('scrollIndicator');
const scrollIndicatorEltTwo = document.getElementById('scrollIndicator2');
var footerHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0].clientHeight

const maxScrollableHeight = (document.body.scrollHeight - footerHeight) - window.innerHeight;

//USE THE BELOW TO SEE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN INCLUDING AND NOT INCLUDING FOOTER HEIGHT
//const maxScrollableHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight

window.addEventListener('scroll', moveScrollIndicator);

function moveScrollIndicator() {
  const percentage = ((window.scrollY) / maxScrollableHeight) * 100;
  if (percentage >= 10) {
    scrollIndicatorElt.style.width = (percentage - 10) + '%';
    scrollIndicatorEltTwo.style.width = percentage + '%';
  } else {
    scrollIndicatorElt.style.width = 0 + '%';
    scrollIndicatorEltTwo.style.width = 0 + '%';
  }
}
```

```css
#scrollIndicator {
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: fixed;
}

#scrollIndicator2 {
  height: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 35px;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div style='height: 1000px; position: relative;'>
  <div class="line" id="scrollIndicator">
  </div>
  <div class="line" id="scrollIndicator2">
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    HERE IS YOUR FOOTER
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works better but the one issue is that the indicator makes a large hop in progress when you hit the 10 mark. It doesn't begin slowly from the far left edge of the screen. Thoughts?

Comment: I just updated the answer. I added a `transition: width 0.3s;` to the `scrollIndicator`. This will prevent that jump and show the progress slower. You can adjust the speed to your liking but I wouldn't recommend making it too slow at it will appear delayed or laggy. I think 0.3s is a good medium.

Comment: Works even better, but what I'm really trying to achieve was to have it start and only count the article area as progress. So while the bar jumps out slower, its progress really reflects about 1/6 read when reality it's only the very beginning. Any way to fix that?

Comment: Ah now I see what you mean. I removed the transition duration and updated the snippet. If it is greater than 10 then I just minus 10 from the percentage. So what is 10 percent is now starting at one percent. I've also added another scroll bar to show the difference. The top one minuses 10 from the percentage, the other does not. The first one is the more accurate indicator that you are looking for.

Comment: Matt, very smart that works great! If I could ask one more question. Let's say the bottom 10% of the page is really the footer. Is there a way to make the snippet end the scroll indicator at full progressed position before the footer?

Comment: I updated the snippet. Just get the height of the footer and minus it from `document.body.scrollHeight` to have the percentage exclude space taken up by the footer. If that's all you need feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: I still can't seem to get this to work. What could be the issue?

Comment: Hi @BILLYMAYSGHOST. What have you changed since last trying to get it to work? Please update the OP as the code I provided seems to satisfy your initial goals.

Comment: Matt, for the "var footerHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0].clientHeight" all is need is the class name of the footer for 'footer'?

Comment: @BILLYMAYSGHOST I'm not sure what you mean. When you say it's not working what do you mean? To get the height of the footer you can use the class selector and `document.getElementsByClassName('YOUR_CLASSNAME')[0]`.